# p/invoke dll loads fine on dev machines but distributed applications (xp/windows7) p/invoke .dll cannot be found

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, pinvoke

We built a project in c# that uses a .dll which we use p/invoke to access functions within the .dll.  It works on our development machines, we can create an installation version of our software which runs fine but if we load it on other xp machines and windows 7 machines which aren't dev machines it reports an error that the .dll that it is trying to p/invoke cannot be found.  The error is repored as the 'the application has failed to start because its side by side configuration is not correct.'

What are we doing wrong?

Thanks, Ron.

Comment: I assume that the DLL you're trying to P/Invoke is actually installed on the client machines? I don't see where you say the DLL you're using is actually part of the CRT. If that's the case, Stu's answer will fix the problem. Otherwise, you'll need to include the DLL with your installer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try installing the VC++ redistributable.

Comment: +1 you are responsible for making sure the C/C++ runtime dlls are on the target system.  Or statically link with them.

Answer (score 1):

Also check that the dll is in the path. It does make a difference, I swear!

Comment: The P/Invoke marshaller in the .NET Framework uses `LoadLibrary` behind the scenes. The default search order (assuming that you do not specify a full path) is given here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682586(v=VS.85).aspx